# Is there an OR operator in spaCy's Matcher patterns?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

Using spaCy 2.x, how to extract noun phrases based on parts of speech? I want to use patterns with spaCy's `Matcher` but combinations are too many to create them manually.

Indeed, in my logic, a noun phrase is a group of one or many tokens that:

- must end with a NOUN token
- can also contain zero, one or many `ADJ, PROPN, NOUN` tokens in any order before the ending NOUN token

For example:

- `NOUN ADJ NOUN`
- `NOUN`
- `ADJ ADJ NOUN NOUN`

Is there an "OR" operator so I could use a pattern such as the below (using an array of matching POS, for example)?

```
matcher.add(

    'NounPhrases', 
    None, 
    [
        {'POS': ['ADJ','NOUN','PROPN'], 'OP': '*'},
        {'POS': 'NOUN'}
    ]
)
```

Comment: use in operator. like this {'TAG': {'IN': ['NN', 'NNS', 'NNP']}